# No sound after OS install. Dummy output

Tags: audio, system-sounds

I have downloaded 3 different OS today, all either Debian or Ubuntu based. Pop OS and Parrot OS both gave me no sound with dummy output showing in sound settings. I Google and found a couple of commands to try but not a fix, at least not for me. Here are the commands and results.

```bash
fuser -v /dev/snd/*

     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND 
/dev/snd/seq:        user       1519 F.... pipewire
```

```bash
ps aux | grep -E pulse\|wire                             
user        1519  0.0  0.1 135060 14764 ?  Ssl  19:53   0:00 /usr/bin/pipewire
user        1520  0.0  0.1 253716 14760 ?        Ssl  19:53   0:00 /usr/bin/wireplumber
user        1521  0.0  0.1  24452  8908 ?        Ssl  19:53   0:00 /usr/bin/pipewire-pulse
user        2929  0.0  0.0   6376   640 pts/1    S+   20:09   0:00 grep --color=auto -E pulse|wire
```

Anyone help me fix this? I’m assuming something isn’t installed and I’m just not having any luck finding out exactly what?

Comment: How does `aplay -l` look?